How To Train GPT-3 On Different Datasets For Different Clients
I am planning on building an ai saas product that would focus on CRM and customer support. However, the bot should know about the company that it is answering for.
I checked their docs and did research, but all I could find was fine-tuning. However, I am not sure how to fine tune with separate data-sets for different companies. This way, when someone contacts the support bot on client A's website, it should not use the company data from client b.
Please let me know if you have any information about how I could do this

Hi, check info on how to build RAG with GPT. Google smth like "GPT RAG" and etc.
